# Mac occasionally freezes. Trying to decipher console system.log file

Tags: mojave, plugins

I'm trying to find the reason why my Mac (Mojave 10.14.4) has been locking up. It usually happens while using Cubase 10.0.5 but I want to specifically pinpoint the problem. Seems like it is something with either Cubase, plugins, or dropbox. I've included two snippets of the system.log file at the time of the freeze, before I force restarted the machine. The last line of each snippet is the reboot. Can anyone pinpoint the culprit? The logs look similar but not the same. I've also included screen shots because the text paste looks a bit messy.

Thank you!

**Crash #1:**

```
*WavesLib (0x138eca4d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 19 17:42:54 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[6160]: objc[6160]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesTreeView is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x14a532750) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x138eca500). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 19 17:42:54 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[6160]: objc[6160]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesTreePanel is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x14a5327a0) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x138eca550). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 19 17:42:54 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[6160]: objc[6160]: Class WebPanel is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore (0x7fff96f76630) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x138eca5c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 19 17:42:54 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[6160]: objc[6160]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesTreeDataSource is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x14a532818) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x138eca708). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 19 17:42:55 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[6160]: objc[6160]: Class IZTextField_v1 is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/iZotope Nectar 2 Pitch Editor.vst/Contents/Resources/iZNectar2PitchEditor.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZNectar2PitchEditor (0x11da59150) and /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/RX 7 Mouth De-click.vst/Contents/Resources/iZRX7MouthDeclick.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZRX7MouthDeclick (0x14b827640). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 19 17:43:00 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[6160]: objc[6160]: Class HttpPostDelegate_UniqVinyl_1_80_10 is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/Vinyl.vst3/Contents/MacOS/PluginHooksVST (0x156a7c7d8) and /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/Vinyl.vst3/Contents/Resources/iZVinyl.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZVinyl (0x157272030). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 19 17:43:00 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[6160]: objc[6160]: Class IZTextField_v1 is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/iZotope Nectar 2 Pitch Editor.vst/Contents/Resources/iZNectar2PitchEditor.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZNectar2PitchEditor (0x11da59150) and /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/Vinyl.vst3/Contents/Resources/iZVinyl.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZVinyl (0x1572728c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 19 17:43:33 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[6160]: init OK in TheWindowController
Apr 19 17:44:03 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Apr 19 17:44:10 Noise-Coalition com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.F3E1C1C7-E6B4-4F6F-B76B-1A973ED1AC35[6963]): Caller wanted oneshot behavior for pre-existing instance: caller = Cubase 10
Apr 19 17:44:10 Noise-Coalition com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Apr 19 17:44:43 Noise-Coalition syslogd[38]: ASL Sender Statistics
Apr 19 17:53:48 Noise-Coalition com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.32321387-74CA-444B-9B61-1C3B0A515006[7015]): Caller wanted oneshot behavior for pre-existing instance: caller = Cubase 10
Apr 19 17:55:38 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1555721738 0*
```

**Crash #2**

```
*Apr 16 16:03:02 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesAboutDelegate is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x15fe78688) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x160bf6438). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:02 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesTextFormatter is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x15fe786b0) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x160bf6460). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:02 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesPresetPanel is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x15fe78728) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x160bf64d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:02 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesTreeView is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x15fe78750) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x160bf6500). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:02 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesTreePanel is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x15fe787a0) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x160bf6550). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:02 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class WebPanel is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore (0x7fff8ca59630) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x160bf65c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:02 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class wvWavesV10_0_1_WavesTreeDataSource is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 10.0.vst3/Contents/MacOS/WaveShell1-VST3 (0x15fe78818) and /Applications/Waves/Plug-Ins V10/WavesLib1_10.0.framework/Versions/A/WavesLib (0x160bf6708). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:05 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class IZTextField_v1 is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/iZotope Nectar 2 Pitch Editor.vst/Contents/Resources/iZNectar2PitchEditor.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZNectar2PitchEditor (0x12697d150) and /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/Nectar 3.vst3/Contents/Resources/iZNectar3.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZNectar3 (0x17784fb90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:08 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class HttpPostDelegate_UniqVSYN_2_01_257 is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/VocalSynth 2.vst3/Contents/MacOS/PluginHooksVST (0x16b329ef8) and /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/VocalSynth 2.vst3/Contents/Resources/iZVocalSynth2.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZVocalSynth2 (0x181984c88). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:03:08 Noise-Coalition Cubase 10[4956]: objc[4956]: Class IZTextField_v1 is implemented in both /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/iZotope Nectar 2 Pitch Editor.vst/Contents/Resources/iZNectar2PitchEditor.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZNectar2PitchEditor (0x12697d150) and /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/VocalSynth 2.vst3/Contents/Resources/iZVocalSynth2.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iZVocalSynth2 (0x181985598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 16 16:05:57 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1555455957 0*
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks more like a Waves issue than Cubase - I'd give them a shout too, they're very helpful - or try going back to Waves 9. [I'm falling behind these days, Cubase 8 & Waves 9, but I've had no similar incidents]

Comment: Be aware that the vast majority of system logging in Mojave no longer lands in system.log.  Apple has shifted most logging into their own subsystem, and only ancient / legacy tools still log to system.log.  the `log` tool in the CLI ( e.g. `log show --info --last 1h` or whatever parameters make sense for your case) may show more information than what's available in the old syslog.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for just ["Noise-Coalition Cubase crash"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Noise-Coalition%20Cubase%20crash&oq=Noise-Coalition%20Cubase%20crash&aqs=chrome..69i57.2200j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) turned up a lot of results that I would consider good candidates from making me highly suspicious of Cubase.

I wouldn't even bother looking at the system logs and direct my attention to your specific version of Cubase that you're running and making sure that it's as up to date and patched as possible.

After doing that I'd get any logging on the application itself instead of the OS, since the crashing is likely coming from this application.

Once you have some logs I'd raise my issue on [Cubase's website](https://helpcenter.steinberg.de/hc/en-us). I'd focus my attention to either their helpcenter of community areas to get more targeted help.

- [helpcenter](https://helpcenter.steinberg.de/hc/en-us)
- [forums](https://www.steinberg.net/en/community/forum.html)